# Android downloading

Tags: android

I downloaded the Android SDK installer file and when i installed it, it launches the SDK manager which then installs many things. i have the following doubts

1. Are the things which the Android SDK manager asks us for installing essential because i have a very slow Internet connection and the file size under SDK manager is too high.
2. Secondly if files under SDK manager can be downloaded on a different computer with high speed Internet connection and then can be copied to my computer ? Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It really depends on what the minimum platform is that you are targeting for your app.  If your minimum platform will be android-14, don't download android-7, for example, because you won't need it.
2. As far as I know (without testing it) you should be able to just copy your android-N folders to your {sdk-path}/platforms directory.

Comment: How to do that? Can you explain a bit?

Comment: I figure that you'd just run the SDK manager on the machine with a fast connection and select the platforms that you'll want to install (for instance android-10).  When the download and installation is complete, go to the platforms directory on that machine, and copy the {sdk-path}/platforms/android-10 folder to your other machine.  On the slow connection machine, open up the sdk manager and see if it picks up the platform that you just copied over.

Comment: I want the latest platform, if i am not wrong the latest one is 4.0.3 ? So in the SDK Manager box i should select everything below Android 4.0.3 i.e. things like Documentation, Samples for SDk etc on fast connection machine and let everything get installed. Now on slow connection machine where should i copy the path of high connection machine installation you have mentioned? Please help i am really new.

Comment: OK, so on the slow connection machine you want to go to Android SDK Location on that machine and copy the android-15 folder (this is 4.0.3) to the platforms folder on that machine.  This assumes the android sdk is installed on the slow connection machine.

Comment: OK so this is what i understood from your explanation------On high speed machine install the Android SDK + all things under Android SDK Manager(path of installation is "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk")----------On slow speed machine install the Android SDK(which i have done) but do not open the Android SDK manager box(the path again is set to "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk") now copy all the things from the path "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platforms" of high speed machine to path "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platforms" of slow speed machine ? Am i correct ?

Comment: That is correct.  The final step will be to open up the SDK Manager and verify it has picked up those API levels as Installed (on the slow connection machine).  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Steve what you said works.